# EventHandler always null within overriden SignalR OnConnected method

Tags: c#, events, signalr

I have a class inheriting from the SignalR Hub class and am overriding the OnConnected Task. When a client connects, OnConnected is fired, but I want to bubble that up to the Processor class using an EventHandler. Unfortunately, the EventHanlder is ALWAYS null. Any thoughts?

```
public class LoadBalancerHub : Hub
{
    public event EventHandler ClientConnected;

    public LoadBalancerHub() : base()
    {
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        ClientConnected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}



public class Processor
{
    public LoadBalancerHub Hub;

    public Processor()
    {
        Hub = new LoadBalancerHub();

        Hub.ClientConnected += Hub_ClientConnected;
    }

    private void Hub_ClientConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff here when event raised
    }
}
```

Comment: Hubs appear to be managed by SignalR pipeline and are transient to the current request. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server for more info. Would you be opened to have a singleton doing the bridge between the hub and the processor?

Comment: You need to read [mcve] and then provide us with one.

Comment: Nothing further is required, IMO. Thanks for you input, though.

Comment: @StfBln That is definitely the issue here. Thanks! I will update with my solution once it's written.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right to me. When you debug, will the handler become valid in this line?
  *Hub.ClientConnected += Hub_ClientConnected;*

What if you have more than one of the LoadBalancerHub object, and the one that fires OnConnected() was not subscribed to...